# Mi Yodeya Launch Party!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, launch

[image: Launch Party Ad]

### Welcome to the Mi Yodeya Launch Party!

If you're not familiar with Mi Yodeya - Stack Exchange yet, go check out our aweseome Jewish Q&A community at **[mi.yodeya.com](http://mi.yodeya.com)**.

#### When

**If you're looking for the Mi Yodeya Launch Party, you've come to the right place. However, the party has concluded — it ran for an hour on June 3, '12. See [below](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1162/2) for show notes, including archived audio and chatroom transcript.**

#### Where

The party is simultaneously in two places:

- An online radio show that you'll be able to listen to [here](http://www.blogtalkradio.com/miyodeya/2012/06/03/mi-yodeya-launch-party) and call into at **+1-347-633-9520**. You can also listen by calling in. If you want us to bring you onto the show, press 1 when you call in; if you just want to listen, don't.

  [image: Radio Show]
- Mi Yodeya's text-based chat room, [V'dibarta Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam). Anyone can "listen in" there, and anyone with [an account](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) here and just 20 [reputation points](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) can [join in](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat).

  [V'dibarta Bam http://cdn.sstatic.net/judaism/img/logo.png?v=1fbf02f6edde](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam)

#### What

The party features:

- A conversation with **[Rabbi Gil Student](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gil_Student)**, Founder and Author of the [Hirhurim - TorahMusings.com](http://torahmusings.com/) blog on

  ***Learning with the Crowd: Judaism on the Internet***
- Your calls
- Games
- Words of Torah from Mi Yodeya community members
- Globe-spanning [Lechaims](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/l%27chaim) (So please have your favorite beverage ready!)

We look forward to partying with you!

Answer (score 6):

### Show Notes

- About 40 people listened live, and a growing number have listened to the audio after the fact.
- [Archived Audio](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/mi-yodeya-launch-party) (Note: When we did the party live, we ran out of time before completing the credits. The archived version has full credits edited in at the end.)
- [Chatroom transcript (extends past the hour covered by the audio)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/launch-party-extended-chat)

#### Useful links and information mentioned in the show:

- [Joel Spolsky](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/503/joel-spolsky) and [Jeff Atwood](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/484/jeff-atwood) created a model for Q&A ["communities... on everything from martial arts to mathematics"](http://stackexchange.com).
- Alex talked about [Numbers 10:35-36](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9938#v35), ["two verses that are marked off", discussed](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&pgnum=122) in the [*K'li Yakar*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Ephraim_Luntschitz).
- [Rabbi Gil Student](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gil_Student) runs [the Hirhurim blog AKA `torahmusings.com`](http://torahmusings.com/).
- Rabbi Student mentioned early Judaism activity on the Internet on email lists like [Mail-Jewish](http://mj.bu.edu/), [Avodah, Areivim](http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/), and [AishDas](http://www.aishdas.org/index.shtml)
- Isaac mentioned the ["Why is it necessary to ask a Rabbi?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) question on Mi Yodeya.
- Isaac listed some of Mi Yodeya's most-used, non-generic tags: [tefilla](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tefilla), [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat), [parshanut-torah-comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshanut-torah-comment), [blessing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blessing), [food](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food), [kashrut-kosher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kashrut-kosher)
- Isaac mentioned two examples of Mi Yodeya questions about new technology and Halacha: ["Is using a Kindle on Shabbat permitted?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9000) and ["Is it permissible to erase the name of G-d from an E-reader?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7275)
- msh210 (reading for Dave) quoted "a verse in Mal'achi" - [3:16](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2403.htm#16).
- Rabbi Student talked about his TorahMusings post ["The Social Media Challenge: How to use social media to build rather than destroy"](http://torahmusings.com/2012/05/the-social-media-challenge/).
- One of Isaac's favorite Mi Yodeya questions is ["Height of a mezuzah and children"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13604/height-of-a-mezuzah-and-children?answertab=votes).

#### Credits:

You heard the voices of the following Mi Yodeya community members. Thanks very much to our callers!

- [ArghMo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11/arghmo), Caller "Rebecca"
- [Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex), with words of Torah
- [HodofHod](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/883/hodofhod), proposing a Lechaim
- [Isaac Moses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses), Host
- [jake](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/489/jake), Caller
- [msh210](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/170/msh210), Reading [Dave](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/67/dave)'s words of Torah
- [Seth J](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5/seth-j), Caller
- [WAF](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/3/waf), Producer, and running [Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex)'s game

We were honored and edified by the participation of:

- [Rabbi Gil Student](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/7533/gil-student), Special Guest

Many thanks for our awesome theme music to producer, vibraphonist, and pianist Ben Portner. You can find him on Soundcloud at https://soundcloud.com/b-port.

We used the following sounds from [Freesound.org](http://freesound.org):

- [Approx 800 Cheer and Clapping 2.wav](http://www.freesound.org/people/lonemonk/sounds/72836/) by [lonemonk](http://www.freesound.org/people/lonemonk/)
- [shaken.not.stirred.wav](http://www.freesound.org/people/dobroide/sounds/7744/) by [dobroide](http://www.freesound.org/people/dobroide/)
- [tapping a glass 06.wav](http://www.freesound.org/people/klankbeeld/sounds/127664/) by [klankbeeld](http://www.freesound.org/people/klankbeeld/)

Online call-in show apparatus provided by [BlogTalkRadio](http://blogtalkradio.com).

Comment: As an alternative to looking and the number of questions per tag to determine what topics are popular here, one could look at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits , which ranks questions using some combination of views, anonymous feedback, and votes.